# filtering by multiselect attribute displaying values in static block

Tags: magento2, module, product-attribute

When filtering by text attribute type the module block and phtml template retrieve values by attribute code, however its not not returning values on MultiSelect

ive tried the following:

// Build a custom SQL expression using find_in_set
$findInSetConditions = [];
foreach ($desiredValues as $value) {
$findInSetConditions[] = $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
'FIND_IN_SET(?, ' . $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier('e.' . $attributeCode) . ')',
$value
);
}

and originally - >

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
$attributeCode,
['finset' => $value],
'left'
);

in the exception error log:

[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid block type: YourVendor\YourModule\Block\ProductCount

here is the complete code for block
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class ProductCount extends Template
{
protected $productCollectionFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function getProductData($attributeCode, $desiredValues)
{
    // Instantiate product collection
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

    // Build a custom SQL expression using find_in_set
    $findInSetConditions = [];
    foreach ($desiredValues as $value) {
        $findInSetConditions[] = $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'FIND_IN_SET(?, ' . $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier('e.' . $attributeCode) . ')',
            $value
        );
    }

    // Add custom SQL expression to the WHERE clause
    $productCollection->getSelect()->where(implode(' OR ', $findInSetConditions));

    // Add 'name' attribute to the select
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(['name']);

    // Get the count of products with the specified attribute values
    $productCount = $productCollection->getSize();

    // Get the names of products
    $productNames = [];
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $productNames[] = $product->getName();
    }

    return [
        'count' => $productCount,
        'names' => $productNames,
    ];
}
```

}

and the template file

getLayout()->createBlock(\YourVendor\YourModule\Block\ProductCount::class);
$attributeCode = 'camera_type';
$desiredValues = ['bullet'];
$productData = $block->getProductData($attributeCode, $desiredValues);
?>

Number of products with  = :

0) : ?>

```
<h2>List of Products:</h2>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($productData['names'] as $productName) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $productName; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

```
<p>No products found with <?php echo $attributeCode; ?> = <?php echo implode(', ', $desiredValues); ?></p>
```